# Django RSS Feed - Slug Isn't Registered

Tags: django, model, rss, slug

I'm trying to set up a very simple RSS Feed. I've followed the docs, read blog posts, searched this site for similar questions etc but I'm still stuck...

In Model.py

```
class Events(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  date = models.DateField(max_length=10)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

In feeds.py

```
class UpcomingEventsFeed(Feed):
  title = "Upcoming events for ChristChurch School"
  link = "/"
  description = "Information taken from the ChristChurch school website"

  def items(self):
    return Events.objects.order_by('-date')[:10]
```

urls.py

```
feeds = {
  'events': UpcomingEventsFeed,
  }
```

url.py

```
(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}),
(r'^feeds/events/$', UpcomingEventsFeed()),
```

But when I go to /feeds/events/ I get a

```
Slug u'events' isn't registered.
```

[This blogpost](http://michaeltrier.com/2007/08/05/digging-into-django%27s-syndication-framework/) goes into more depth that the docs and suggests that the feeds dictionary isn't synced with my url but I can't see the problem?

Then the other thing that could be an issue is the slug? I've read what a slug is but what do I need to do with it? Do I need to put something in my model like get_absolute_url()?

Appologies if it's a glaring error but I'm a newcomer to the framework and progrmaming in general. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your class Events a get_absotule_url method. This will save you trouble for links in the feed view.
Try to set up your urls.py like this:

```
from your.path.to.feed import UpcomingEventsFeed
#...
(r'^feeds/events/$', UpcomingEventsFeed()),
#...
```

Dont use this line: `(r'^feeds/(?P<url>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.feed', {'feed_dict': feeds}),` it will intercept the call to the second line and throw the error.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I don't really udnerstand the get_absoloute_url() method though how do I put that into my model?

Comment: OK, then please close this thread and open up a new one on your problems with get_absolute_url. Thank you.